# Is there a code coverage tool tor Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am seeking a code coverage tool for Mathematica to determine test coverage.

I know about the Testing Framework, only: 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingTheTestingFramework.html

Answer (score 2):

You can install a paclet named `"Coverage"` the same way as the `"Lint"` paclet described here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192690/12

Once done, restart the system and search the docs for "coverage".

---

Update: This paclet is now called `"Instrumentation"`.

Comment: Is this paclet still actively maintained? I think it is not held on GitHub, so I don't know how it is developed. Running `PacletFindRemote["Coverage"]` returns a newest one with version `0.13`; it lacks a `Description` field, which generally means it is not following the current conventions and is thus not up-to-date.

Comment: I also wonder if there is a way to integrate Mathematica with mainstream coverage tools on GitHub.

Comment: @Gravifer See edit. I would not read much into the lack of description though. You can list all paclets by the same author using `PacletFind["*", "Creator" -> "*Bostick*"]`.

Comment: @Gravifer As for the second question, I would assume yes, since it uses the same format as `gcov`. I have not tried it, but if you do, and succeed, please let me know. Maybe also write a self-answered question on Mathematica.SE.